# Getting error in nodejs when querying mongodb data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting error in nodejs console (see screenshot for more clarification).

In matches.js :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const matchSchema = new Schema({

    match_id:{
        type:Number;     <---- line 8
        required:true;
    },

    season:{
        type:Number;
        required:true;
    }

.....
.....
});

const matches = mongoose.model('matches', matchSchema);

module.exports = matches;

// Get matches
module.exports.getmatches = (callback, limit) => {
    matches.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

In app.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

matches = require('./models/matches');

mongoose.connection.openUri('mongodb://localhost:27017/IPL');
const db = mongoose.connection;

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    matches.getmatches((err, match) => {

        if(err){
            throw err;
        }

        res.json(matches);

    });
});

app.listen('5000');
console.log('Running on port 5000....')
```

I have made model folder which contains matches.js I am trying to access data from mongodb and when to display it as JSON data on API endpoint i.e `localhost://5000/home`

[image]

Comment: On line 8-9, you will have to replace the semicolons with commas (to make it a valid json object)

Comment: @Brain done still gives error

Comment: @brain got it if you give short answer I can upvote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic JavaScript Object declaration error. A JSON Object should look like this,

```
{
   match_id: {
     type: Number,    //see the comma there?
     required: true
   }
}
```

Instead of using `,`, you have used `;` which will throw a syntax error. use this instead,

```
const matchSchema = new Schema({
    match_id: {
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    season: {
        type:Number,
        required:true
    }
    .....
    .....
});
```

Also, your `getmatches` function requires a limit passed as the second parameter, you need to pass that as well in the code.